# Find how many days a value appears in a dataset python through distinctDay

Tags: python, pandas, count, distinct, analytics

I have a dataset with only 3 features. The features are person, movie and day.I want to find how many different days a person sees a certain movie. So for each person, i want to count how many days she has seen that movie. If possible, maybe even appear how many times in each day, but the main focus is how many days.

```
                    movie          person         Day
0                  le vie            john  2017-09-21
1                 friends           sarah  2017-09-21
2                 giraffe          maggie  2017-09-21
3                   maome            mark  2017-09-21
4                  tarzan            faby  2017-09-25
5                  heaven           elisa  2017-09-25
6                    moon            lucy  2017-09-25
7               king kong          philip  2017-09-25
8              la la land          hannah  2017-09-25
```

It continues for thousands of rows.
Anyone has any ideia, i've tried mostly groupbys but i'm not sure i can get what i want from that. Appreciate the help.
Thanks,

Comment: It could be helpful if you posted the output for your example.

Comment: What's with the weird column names? Shouldn't the first two be "movie" and "viewer" or something similar?

Comment: Are you using `pandas`?  That's what it looks like, but wanted to verify.

Comment: What's the datatype of the "ts" column? Strings?

Comment: @timgeb Sorry, my mistake

Comment: @vealkind yes, i'm using pandas, it's a dataframe

Comment: @timgeb no, i transformed it to datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(assuming you're using pandas)

How about something like this:

```
df.groupby(['actor', 'action_query_phone']).Day.nunique()
```

This gives you how many days each person watched each movie (not showing entries with 0 days watched)

Comment: Thank you for answering, i tried it, but It gives the error: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'ts'

Comment: An i wrote Day because i had made a mistake in the column name, but it gives that error anyway

Comment: Try again... I was expecting the column to be named `ts`

Comment: using unique() instead of nonunique() i was able to get the days in wich an actor saw the same movie, but wasn't able to get the number

Comment: It worked, thank you. Just a correction, it should be nunique() instead of nonunique()

Comment: Is there anyway i can acess this result to use the column of counts or just consult?